# How to setup Laravel Many to Many-relationship with intermediate table which is not only a pivot table, but also represents a Model

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have a table which looks like the following;

```
Table: offers          (Model: Offer)
  id

Table: clients         (Model: Client)
  id

Table: offer_requests  (Model: OfferRequest)
  id
  offer_id
  client_id
```

So, the relations should be something like;

- `offer` has multiple `offer_requests`
- `offer` has multiple `clients` (through `offer_requests`)
- `client` has multiple `offer_requests`
- `client` has multiple `offers` (through `offer_requests`)
- `offer_request` belongs to one `offer`
- `offer_request` belongs to one `client`

What i can figure out is;

- `offer` hasMany `offer_requests` --- Inverse: `offer_request` belongsTo `offer`
- `client` hasMany `offer_requests` --- Inverse: `offer_request` belongsTo `client`

What i can't figure out;

- `offer` has multiple `clients` through `offer_requests`
- `client` has multiple `offers` through `offer_requests`

If i read the manual carefully, a hasManyThrough relationship does'nt work here. I think this should be a Many to Many relationship.

If i'm right: how can i use the `offer_requests` table  as intermediate/pivot table?
If i'm not: how to solve this?

---

**Update: Working**

I have now setup the relation as following;

Model: Offer

```
class Offer extends Model
{
    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Client::class, 'offer_requests')->using(OfferRequest::class);
    }
}
```

Model: Client

```
class Client extends Model
{
    public function offers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Offer::class, 'offer_requests')->using(OfferRequest::class);
    }
}
```

Model: OfferRequest

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class OfferRequest extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'offer_requests';
}
```

Comment: `hasManyThrough` is only for a chain of one to many. had to use many to many instead - [`hasMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). and use `->pivot` to retrieve the data on the pivot or intermediate table. and `hasMany` for many-to-many uses `belongsToMany` instead of `belongsTo`..

Comment: @BagusTesa But `offer_requests` is already the pivot table here. What would the models look like? Just `hasMany` on both `Offer` and `Client` with the table name specified? And should there be anything on the `OfferRequest`?

Comment: Hi @RamonBakker, pivot table are not mandatory to be a table, you can define it on the `hasMany` relation, example on the docs `$this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');`. the first parameter is the other model, next one is the table name, followed with key of the current model on the pivot  followed with the other key on the pivot. cmiiw. its been awhile since my last laravel. take it with grain and salt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[look at docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models

Comment: I setup my relation as custom intermediate table. However, new questions come up. Do i need to set the intermediate table name in the belongsToMany method? And can i use `->as('offers')` or is this automaticly done?

Comment: if you customize the name of pivot table otherwise no need. In your case NO need to use `->as`

Comment: I've added my setup to the question. If i may ask, can you have a look at it?

Comment: Thanks! I think it should be working now :) Ill test it in a minute

Comment: Actually, i had to define the table `offer_requests` in the second belongsToMany method parameter. Also i added `protected $table = 'offer_requests';` to the OfferRequest model. With those added, it's working perfectly!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help...happy coding

Answer (score 2):

you can make it two one to many relationship

Comment: Then i have to maintain 2 additional pivot tables, while i already have one

Comment: I think he means that a m2m relationship can be seen as 2 oneToMany relationships with the pivot model like so:
User -> o2m UserComments <- o2m Comments